# Illegal instruction: 4 when executing php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel

I am new with Laravel and working on a project to practice myself. I have set up and connected my database and when I try to execute the migrate command on the VS Code terminal, I get the error: Illegal Instruction: 4

I have seen different discussions but was not able to find one with good instructions to solve this.
Most of them were for other programs and not Laravel/VS Code.(also I am a Mac user)

Any ideas on this and how to solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsrIh.png)

Comment: Do you have a database? Have you connected it? Have you added it in the `.env` file? There can be so many reasons, please add clarity and edit the question, otherwise, it will receive more downvotes.

Comment: I know, just edited, yes I have a database and have connected it, added to the .env file.
Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Ok. Are you running the command from `project's root file`? Are you using `XAMPP`? Is `MYSQL` running?

Comment: @Rob Yes using XAMPP and MySQL is running. Command from project's root file
using VS Code integrated terminal

Comment: Restart apache from XAMPP.

Comment: Did that, same thing again

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to occur if you have SSL issues or config issues in the options section.

It may be how the composer runs from a root directory and it cannot find the real path of a SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced this due to an incorrect configuration on Symfony[*] where the the mysql port was set to 33060 instead of 3306.

I think you can get this error if your mysql configuration is pointing to the wrong host/port combination, possibly combined with SSL enabled.

- The issue is in the php mysql layer so which framework is in use is not so important.

Answer (score -1):

> You are trying outside the project folder you should go inside your project folder

```
cd YOUR_FOLDER_NAME
```

> then

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I am using VS Code integrated terminal so I am inside my project folder, but I have tried using Mac terminal and got inside my project folder, still when doing php artisan migrate with say Illegal Instruction: 4

Comment: Restart apache then check here some solution for you https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6494

Comment: tried restarting apache using sudo apachectl -k restart
I get this error: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using MacBook-Pro-di-User.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: Restarted apache and I have checked that solution, but does not work for me